# Como associar uma imagem diferente aos itens de menu?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, imagem, css-hover

Eu estou criando um menu para um site, onde nele está listado as áreas de atuação da empresa.
Eu gostaria que quando o usuário passa-se o mouse no texto a `div` lateral exibisse uma imagem equivalente à categoria, mas não tenho ideia de como faz.
[image: Imagem Exemplo]

Já usei um CSS que era com base em `display: none` e `display: flex` com as classes, onde o texto tinha a classe de mostrar e a foto de esconder, mas não funcionou.
Código HTML do menu da primeira coluna:

````
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAbat">Abatedouros</span>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAgro">Agroindústria</span>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAgropecuaria">Agropecuária Familiar</span>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAgua">Água</span>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAlimentos">Alimentos</span>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarCer">Cerâmica</span>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarConstrucao">Construção Civil</span>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarEnergia">Energia</span>
</a></li>
</ul> ```
````

Comment: Você pode usar os eventos de mouse ([mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) ou [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event)) do JS e no caso do CSS você pode colocar um contêiner como irmão dos itens de menu e aplicar o [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) nos mesmos e usar o [seletor de irmão](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#adjacent_sibling_combinator) para mudar a imagem do contêiner.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de fazer isso com CSS pegando do elemento pai e passando a mostrar os elementos filhos:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAbat">Abatedouros</span>
<div>
Conteúdo Abatedouros 
</div>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAgro">Agroindústria</span>
<div>
Conteúdo Agroindústria 
</div>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAgropecuaria">Agropecuária Familiar</span>
<div>
Conteúdo Agropecuária Familia
</div>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAgua">Água</span>
<div>
Conteúdo Água
</div>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarAlimentos">Alimentos</span>
<div>
Conteúdo Alimentos
</div>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarCer">Cerâmica</span>
<div>
Conteúdo Cerâmica
</div>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarConstrucao">Construção Civil</span>
<div>
Conteúdo Construção Civil
</div>
</a></li>
    <li><a href="">
<span class="mostrarEnergia">Energia</span>
<div>
Conteúdo Energia
</div>
</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>

<div class="janela">
Teste
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
.container .menu {
  width: 70%;
} 
.container .menu ul li a div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: gray;
    height: 400px;
    width: 280px;
    top: 0;
}
.container .janela {
  border: 1px solid #000;
 
   height: 400px;
   display:flex;
   width: 28%;
  
}
ul  {
 display: flex;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 70%;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 
 
}
ul li {
list-style:none;
padding: 10px;
}

.container .menu ul li a:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

[Exemplo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1whbks63/)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode atribuir um atributo com a url da imagem ao `.span`, por exemplo:

```
`<li><a href=""><span class="mostrarAbat menuImagem" imagem="abatedouro.png">Abatedouros</span></a></li>`
```

E por javascript uma função que seja executada no hover da classe `menuImagem`, exemplo abaixo, neste hover irá ser capturado o atributo com o nome da imagem, e exibi-lo numa `img`

```
  $(".menuImagem").on("mouseover", function()
  {
    var imagemdoMenu = $(this).attr("imagem");
    $("#menu_imagem").attr("src", imagemdoMenu );
  })
```

Checa um exemplo simples: https://jsfiddle.net/sNniffer/eb23sr1o/1/

Comment: Estou utilizando Wordpress para desenvolver os sites e por lá não consigo usar o JQuery, podes me dizer como faço por Javascript?

Comment: Oi @GabrielMorona, quase da mesma forma é possível fazer no wordpress, basta no javascript que informei você trocar as tags `$` pela palavra `jQuery`